# How to use bash command completion so that only files within a particular directory are completed?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, compgen

Suppose I have a bash function `specialcat` that `cat`s a file in the ~/Special directory

```
specialcat () {
    cat ~/Special/$1
}
```

Suppose the ~/Special directory was set up like so:

```
mkdir ~/Special
echo This is the first special file > ~/Special/firstfile
echo This is the second special file > ~/Special/secondfile
```

The specialcat function is used like:

```
> specialcat firstfile
This is the first special file
```

I want to enable argument completion so that

```
> specialcat firstf[TAB]
```

produces

```
> specialcat firstfile
```

regardless of what the current working directory is and what files happen to be there.

This is my attempt so far

```
_options_specialcat () {
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$(ls ~/Special)") )
}

complete -F _options_specialcat specialcat
```

which leads to

```
> specialcat firstf[TAB]
firstfile   secondfile  
> specialcat firstf
```

That is, pressing tab on a partial file name will display the list of files, but will not complete the command.

How do I alter my `_options_specialcat` function to produce the desired behavior?

Comment: `COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$(ls ~/Special)" -- "$1") )`

Comment: Now nothing happens when I TAB. I'm on OSX if that makes a difference.

Comment: I changed it to `COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$(ls ~/Special)" -- "$2") )` and it worked! If you post as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter the list by the current argument, so:

```
COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$(ls ~/Special)" -- "$2") )
```

Comment: For future readers, you can also access the current word with `${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}` rather than hard-coding the parameter number.